# Compound TextView Padding Issue

Tags: android

Please refer to this image:
[image]

The Top image is a `TextView` with no compound drawable and the padding all around seems perfect.

The second image has a compound image using `android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_expand"` and the image messes up all the padding.

How to get rid of this unwanted padding in the second image ?

Here's the XML

```
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/moreinfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/translucent_black"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_expand"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/content_heading_padding"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/content_heading_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/content_size"
                android:text="@string/more_info" />
```

As you can see in the XML i have used `android:drawablePadding` 
Including or removing that line does changes the padding for the drawable but the mess that has happened for the textview still remains.

I have tried negative padding values for `android:drawablePadding` but it does not correct the issue.

Comment: I think you can fix this issue by adding `android:gravity="left | center_vertical"` to your TextView

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be that it must be set autoresizable(true) in your android manifest file set to autoresizable(true). Check your manifest.